# android intent filter with single activity architecture

Tags: android, android-fragments, intentfilter

im currently working on an app, and i want to be able to share images to my app.

with multiple activities this doesn't seem to be a problem, since you define your activity as intent receiver. 
however how would i do this, with the single activity architecture google is pushing with its navigation api ?

should the single main activity handle it or does it make sense to create a second activity in this scenario.

i couldn't really find anything on that topic in the android dev docs

Comment: What's with the navigation api? The single main activity can use as many intent filters as you want.

Comment: Did you try using Deep Links? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link

Comment: @LoWaiKiu yes but then i have to manually navigate to the fragment right 
so when i press back it goes back to the previous fragment and not the app which started the indent

Comment: @ramtintoosi yes but then i have the same issue as described in the other comment:
the back button will not go back the to the intent that started but to the previous fragment

Comment: Please provide the code you used to open specific fragments with deep links.

Comment: @ramtintoosi so my app currently consists of 2 fragments a list and a detail, when i receive a SEND Intent i want to go to the detail fragment 
https://gist.github.com/FelixStumvoll/4175325881ff46c8f79206914a3c89c2
this is how i switch to it manually

Comment: I posted an answer, I tested it and it worked for me. please check and let me know if it's true

Comment: any luck with this issue?. i am facing this same issue.

Comment: @faizy i solved it by handling the intent in the main activity and then using the nav controller to redirect to the desired page

Comment: @FelixStumvoll, could you please add it as answer here?. That will be much helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Uri to your navController instead of navigating manually by fragment id.

```
val deeplink = Uri.parse("android-app://androidx.navigation.app/yourFragmentId")
findNavController().navigate(deeplink)
```

Unlike navigation using action or destination IDs, you can navigate to any URI in your graph, regardless of whether the destination is visible. You can navigate to a destination on the current graph or a destination on a completely different graph.

When navigating using URI, the back stack is not reset. This is unlike other deep link navigation, where the back stack is replaced when navigating. popUpTo and popUpToInclusive, however, still remove destinations from the back stack just as though you had navigated using an ID.

Comment: do you have a link for this 
cause i can't find it in any documentation :c

Comment: @FelixStumvoll https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#uri